What are the results of the MELISSA project?
The project has been running for 30 years. In their FAQ they write that

We have seen over the years many similar projects : CELSS, CEEF,
CERES, BIOSPHERE 2… almost all of them had to stop due to incorrect
evaluation of the challenges, and necessary amplitude and duration of
the efforts.

So what are they doing differently and what are their results?

What MELISSA is doing differently (from, say, Biosphere2)  is break the process down into isolated steps which are only allowed to interact in restricted, controllable ways:
-Liquefaction compartment
-Photoheterotrophic compartment
-Nitrifying compartment
-Photoautotrophic compartment (separate algae and higher plant
compartments)
This strategy has more in common with a chemical engineering process than an ecosystem, but it has advantages. It allows conditions to be optimized in each compartment without compromising conditions in other compartments.
For instance, CO2 level can be optimized independently for O2 production in the algae compartment and  for food production in the higher plants compartment.
Another example is temperature optimization. The Liquefaction compartment is held at 55C for optimal breakdown while the cyanobacterium is held at 21C for optimal growth.
The pH of the cyanobacterium compartment is significantly higher than that for the higher plants, despite both being photosynthetic compartments.
By breaking the process into independent stages, this allows  researchers from 50 organizations https://www.melissafoundation.org/page/melissa-project to pursue different strategies to achieve pre-determined goals and to compare “apples to apples” in their results. Since compartments only interact within specified parameters, it allows wide collaboration between separate research centers .
MELISSA has yet to create a human-rated closed system suitable for use in space exploration. But then, neither has anyone else. However, it has demonstrated CO2/O2 recycling with edible biomass production in their rat-populated pilot plant in Spain. They have made progress in recycling nitrogen-based waste for fertilizer and developed bioreactors which have been tested on the ISS.
As always, “more research is needed”. There are plans to test the overall system in spaceflight in the 2030s. https://www.euro-case.org/strategic-performance-assessment-for-esas-melissa-project
